# RowLimit not working in PowerShell Get-PnPListitem

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, caml-query, pnp-powershell

I am trying to get few items from SharePoint list so I am using `RowLimit` in a query, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$query = "<View><Query>
<Where><Eq> <FieldRef Name='StatusN'/><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ReleaseDate'/></OrderBy>
</Query>
<RowLimit>2</RowLimit> 
 </View>";
 $Numbers = (Get-PnPListitem -List JML_TC_DDIsAll -Query $query).FieldValues
```

But I still get more than 2 items. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are some issues with `RowLimit` while using PnP PowerShell.

Try this instead:

```
$query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq> <FieldRef Name='StatusN'/><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ReleaseDate'/></OrderBy></Query></View>";
$Numbers = (Get-PnPListitem -List JML_TC_DDIsAll -Query $query -PageSize 4 | select -first 2).FieldValues
```

**GitHub Issues**:

1. [Get-PNPListItem query parameter ignores Paged attribute in RowLimit](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/879)
2. [Get-PnPListItem: PageSize parameter does nothing](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2143)

**Similar Thread**: [RowLimit not working in SharePoint Online CAML query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064343/rowlimit-not-working-in-sharepoint-online-caml-query) - Check comments on answer by Jerry.

Comment: But if I have 3000 rows in the list, will it download all 3000 items just to get few of them? I only need 2 first items from that list